# When I try to replace a portion of a numpy array, nothing happens

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following code

currSub is a Dataframe with length 2850, and I extract the timestamps (the numbers 1 to 2850) and a vector of probabilities of the same length.

My Goal is to place the vector currProb inside the vector realign, starting at the position 50, and leaving the other zeros unchanged.

When I run either of the last two lines, just nothing happens at all. Can someone explain why the values don't change?

```
alignPoint = 50
x = np.arange(0,3000)

subTimes = np.arange(2850)/2
subProb = np.ones(2850)-0.5
        
realign = np.zeros_like(x)
sTRe = np.arange(alignPoint,alignPoint+len(subTimes)).astype(int)

realign[alignPoint:alignPoint+len(subTimes)] = subProb
np.put(realign,sTRe,subProb)
```

Comment: You have `subProb` but not `currSub` or `currProb`.

Answer (score 0):

`realign` has dtype `int64`. When you assign floating-point values to it, they get converted to the integer type, which means they are rounded down.

Since `subProb` contains 0.5, you replace existing 0 values by new 0 values.

To avoid this, create `realign` with the same dtype as `subProb`:

```
realign = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=subProb.dtype)
```